# Find Active Record object where multiple associations match (same field)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

For example, I have a `Product` and a `Favorite` association:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorites
end
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to: user
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorites
end
```

How could I find products that user with id `1` and user with id `2` have favorited? Even better, products that only those two users have favorited (nobody else has favorited it).

I've tried joining multiple `where` queries, but that doesn't return any results. I've spent a solid while searching for an answer, but I'm really just hitting a wall.

This was my latest attempt:

```
Product.includes(:favorites).where(favorites: { user_id: 1 }).where(favorites: { user_id: 2 })
```

Comment: Do you mean products both users have favorited, or that either user has favorited?

Comment: @dodecaphonic Both

Answer (score 2):

If you mean Products either user has favorited, what you're looking for is something like:

```
Product.joins(:favorites).where(favorites: { user_id: [1, 2] })
```

If, however, you're looking for those Products favorited by *both* users, the solution is to use `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT products.id
FROM products INNER JOIN favorites 
  ON favorites.product_id = products.id
WHERE favorites.user_id = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT id
FROM products INNER JOIN favorites 
  ON favorites.product_id = products.id
WHERE favorites.user_id = 2
```

There's no convenient way to write that as an ActiveRecord chain (i.e. you'll probably find yourself using `find_by_sql`), but it's doable in Arel.

Comment: I'm getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous`.

Comment: I've got it working with `Product.joins(:favorites).where(favorites: { user_id: 1 }).merge(Product.joins(:favorites).where(favorites: { user_id: 2 }))`. I wouldn't have been able to find `merge` without looking up the above error, though!

Comment: Right. I should have explicitly scoped `id`.

Comment: Right. If I'm not mistaken, `merge` will not achieve what you want — it will instead make the latter condition win. It will only return an intersection if you pass in an array as its argument.

Comment: That said, if it's working and I'm mistaken, I hope you remember `INTERSECT` in the future, as you let the database do the work for you, instead of dispatching two queries and computing the intersection in memory.

Comment: It seems to work for all of my use cases in my tests, including inversing each of them. However, I would love to figure out how to get `INTERSECT` working. What do you mean by 'explicitly scop[ing] `id`'?

Comment: I mean determining `favorites.id` as the column I wish to build the sets with (the set of products favorite by user A and the set of products favorited by user B. INTERSECT would then find the ids in both sets and return that resulting set). It doesn't have to be a single column, mind you — I was just restricting the example.